# Using a data source for a Web performance test that is encrypting password

Tags: performance-testing, mstest, load-testing

In my visual studio webtest I currently have a password field that encrypts the password after i recorded it. I wanted to data drive my web-test so i data bind the form's post parameter with my data source that is not encrypted which is failing the webtest, since its putting in the plain password instead of the encrypted password since the recorder recorded the encrypted password.

What are my options to be able to data drive the test with the different user name using my plain password or is there a way for me to encrypt the password even not knowing what is used to encrypt the password.  Thanks.

Comment: Where is the password being encrypted? I guess by some Javascript  (or another scripting language) running in the browser. Can you study that script and find the encryption code? Alternatively, what value is being recorded for the password in the webtest? If you record a login for the same user more than once are all the encrypted values the same? What happens if you put the encrypted value into your data source? What happens if different users have the same password, is the same encrypted value sent? I have run tests with hundreds of users all having the same password.

Comment: You have asked a couple of interesting questions but not provided enough information to give answers. So I have asked for clarifications. How are you getting on with these questions? If you have found solutions then please write them up as answers. Otherwise, please consider adding more details.

Comment: @AdrianHHH sorry i'm working on an internal application, that i was trying to load test.  The password is being encrypted just before its submitted. I believe its using some ajax scripting.  I was at the beginning phases of trying to figure it out.  As far as solutions. I haven't really came up with a solution, I plan on keeping the user passwords the same to see if i can reuse the encrypted password for all the users.